# 3 level menu with bad sql database

Tags: mysql

I have to make a vertical 3 level's menu based on database items but unfortunatelly not organised with "parent_id"...

The db look like :

```
 menu    |  sub menu  |  subsub menu  |  subsubsub menu
________________________________________________________
univers1 |   galaxy1  |    planet1    |  city1

univers1 |   galaxy1  |    planet1    |  city2

univers1 |   galaxy2  |    planet1    |  city1

univers1 |   galaxy2  |    planet2    |  city1

univers1 |   galaxy2  |    planet2    |  city2

univers2 |   galaxy1  |    planet1    |  city1

univers2 |   galaxy2  |               |  

univers2 |   galaxy3  |    planet1    |
```

And I need to obtain :

- univers1

  - galaxy1

    - planet1

      - city1
      - city2
    - planet2

      - city1
  - galaxy2

    - planet1

      - city1
    - planet2

      - city1
      - city2
- univers2

  - galaxy1

    - planet1

      - city1
  - galaxy2
  - galaxy3

    - planet1

I know it's bad, but I have no choice for this one.

I should admit that without the traditional parent_id column I'm quite confused.

Is there a special trick with mysql to keep request simple ?
I mean without using interval tree.

Comment: What exactly you want do it? What you want in result?

Comment: Please state what exactly the problem is. At the moment, it is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: In fact I need to "clear" this request to only have one of each result. To structure the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to use linked tables? It won't require a parent_id from to be send as parameter. On top of that it will create a clear and simple structure of 4 tables which is proper form and does not duplicate data.

For example:

```
TABLE UNIVERSE
ID UniverseName UniverseStatus ....

TABLE GALAXY
ID GalaxyName UniverseId GalaxyStatus ...
```

etc.
Note the ID's are auto-generated and increased at creation.
If that's not the case you can use something like

```
SELECT city FROM mainTable WHERE {conditions}
```

You could bundle the conditions